# reduce (fold) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any reduce/fold implementations for Pandas DataFrame?
For example, I want to get sum of numbers in column named `cost` in dataframe `df`, using something like `lambda acc, x`, where `x` is a DataFrame row.

What should I do?

P.S. I know about .sum(), but there are many other possible `\acc,x -> ...` functions.

Comment: You can probably accomplish this using `.apply` with `lambda` and `reduce`, but be warned: this will be very inefficient, and you should stick to built-in ufuncs if you care about speed. Or implement your own.

Comment: This is pretty frustrating that such a basic data structure does not have a native reduce/fold function that accumulates things.

Answer (score 1):

A fast fold is available in the following way (replace `plus` with your own function):

```
import numpy as np
def accum(op,ser):
    u_op = np.frompyfunc(op, 2, 1) # two inputs, one output
    return u_op.accumulate(ser, dtype=np.object)
def plus(x,y):
    return x+y
accum(plus,np.arange(10))
```

You get:

```
array([0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45], dtype=object)
```

This works for numpy series, and hence also for components of pandas dataframes. It would be interesting to have a solution that directly works on dataframes, such that multiple series can be combined.